# Is there a class or a way that lets you run laravel code via command line?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm managing a website where I need to update its contents by getting rss feeds, I'm always going to my update link/route via web browser to update.

I'm planning to use crontab so that I don't need to manually update it, So is there a way to run that code via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Yes.

Laravel has an extensive [CLI interface](http://laravel.com/docs/commands) which allows you to do exactly that. In these commands, you have access to all Laravel resources as if it was run by the webserver.